# tabbing inputs in Mozilla and IE not scrolling view up

Tags: jquery, html, css, cross-browser

I have a long `form` for the site I'm working on, and there are two columns of `inputs`. When the user tabs through the `inputs` the view scrolls down to keep the focused field in view. When the user reaches the bottom of the first column and the tab focus goes to the top of the second column, the view doesn't scroll up to follow the focus, but only in Mozilla and IE. When I test on Chrome, the view will scroll up to keep the focused input field in view.

Does anyone know how to deal with this cross browser issue and make the page automatically scroll up for Mozilla and IE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem. My view that contained the view that I was trying to tab through was, when scrolled up, hidden behind another view. Chrome realized the view was behind another, but Mozilla didn't.

My solution was to use `scrollTop`. When my input on the top right received the tab focus, I scrolled the view to the top:

```
$("#org-select").on("select2-focus", function(e) { 
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "fast");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not able to reproduce this on any browser, but if you're using jquery, you can try adding this to your javascript and see if it helps.

```
$(function() {
    $("input").on("focus", function() {
         this.scrollIntoView(true);
    });
});
```